# Yielding a modified Ruby array to a block

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I'm trying to turn 2 lines of ruby code into 1.  For example:

```
def average(numbers)
  result = numbers.compact
  numbers.reduce(+) / numbers.length
end
```

I've been looking through array methods and can't find an appropriate one to turn this function into a one-liner.  I had hoped something like this would work:

```
def average(numbers)
  numbers.compact.<tap or another method> { |arr| arr.reduce(+) / arr.length }
end
```

Basically, I'm modifying the array (in the example I have to call compact to rid `nil` values), so I don't have access to the array variable, and I don't want an iterator, because I don't want to call `reduce(+)` and `length` on individual elements of the array.

Does anyone have an idea of methods I could look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean for your method to be the following (`reduce(:+)`, not `reduce(+)` and use `result` rather than `numbers` in the second line).

```
def average(numbers)
  result = numbers.compact
  result.reduce(:+) / result.length
end

average [1,2,3]
  #=> 2
```

If you wish the average to be a float, change the second line to

```
result.reduce(0.0, :+) / result.length
```

There are various ways to combine the two lines of the method, but I don't prefer any of them to the above. Here are a few. (I don't see how [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) could be used here.)

```
numbers.compact.reduce(:+) / numbers.compact.length

(result = numbers.compact).reduce(:+) / result.compact.length

numbers.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) / numbers.compact.length
```

Note that, even if `numbers` can be mutated, one cannot write

```
numbers.compact!.reduce(:+) / numbers.length
```

because `numbers.compact!` returns `nil` if `numbers` contains no `nil` elements.

In Ruby v2.4+ you can use [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum):

```
result.sum / result.length
```

Comment: Cool, I just talked with one of my teammates and we agreed what I have (with your corrections) is best for readability.

Comment: although I did learn something here: `(result = numbers.compact).reduce(:+) / result.compact.length` thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, @Stefan.  I meant to write the calculation of the average as a float as `result.reduce(:+).to_f / result.length`, but I prefer the way you did it.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the way you call `average`

```
def average(numbers)
  numbers.reduce(:+) / numbers.length
end

average(num_array.compact)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm off in the weeds anyway with the "I don't have access to the array variable" part.